# Laravel5 new controller in folder does not exist

Tags: class, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I add a new controller in new folder.
But I got an error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\QRCode\ProductController does not exist

**Here's my new controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class ProductController extends Controller {
 ......
}
```

**And my folder:**

[image: Folder]

But if I put `ProductController` in folder-Controllers, it's work.

I don't know why.

Please help out!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\QRCode;`